# i installed ruby 1.9.2 with RVM, but when i type "ruby -v" is telling me the ruby v i have is 1.8.7 (mac)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

when i write in the treminal "rvm list" i get this:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ x86_64 ]
```

but when i type "ruby -v" i get this:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

what shoud i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `rvm use 1.9.2`?  Installing rubies does not make them the executable version of ruby. RVM will only make `ruby` the 1.9.2 version if you tell it to, with `rvm use 1.9.2` or `rvm use 1.9.1`

If you want rvm to use 1.9.2 by default, use `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

Comment: The result of his *RVM list* command indicates that ruby 1.8.7 is not under RVM management.

Comment: @Jordan Yes, that is generally the case for OS X because it bundles ruby 1.8.7 (usually referred to as the implicity system ruby).  You can always `rvm use system` even though it is not listed in `rvm list`

Comment: I have the same problem. Though I run "rvm use 1.9.2" it doesn't make any difference. Seems like 1.8.7 is not under RVM management. How do I fix that?

Comment: @igorti You should probably make a new question (considering this one is already answered).  If you include the output of `rvm list` and `rvm info` you will likely get some help.  Did you follow all the instructions included in the first link in Jordan's answer?

Comment: @BrettI have RVM setup on my OSX system and 1.8.7 is shown as one of my available Ruby versions with rvm list. As you note, I can run rvm system (the use is not required) and I am able to move between versions.

Comment: @Jordan, you might want to check your RVM version. Previous versions of `rvm list` would show the system Ruby, but that hasn't been true for several revs. I'm on the current rev., which is 1.2.6.

Comment: @Jordan Hmm, strange.  Is it possible you have installed 1.8.7 manually through rvm in the past? Try `rvm system` then `which ruby`, and compare the output against `rvm use 1.8.7` and then `which ruby`? I have `/Users/brett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302` then `/usr/bin/ruby` - if your output for both of those is `/usr/bin/ruby` maybe we have different versions of rvm?

Comment: @Brett - I am on RVM 1.1.2, so I am not on the latest and greatest. My 1.8.7 install was not via RVM.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually looking at your system, I can't say for sure what is happening, but it would appear that you skipped the RVM Post Install step (see [RVM Install page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), which is what loads it into your shell session.

Quoting from the RVM Install page:

Post Install

> The first time you install RVM, you
>   must put the following line into your
>   ~/.bash_profile at the very end, after
>   all path loads etc:
>
> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && ."$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
>
> ## This loads RVM into a shell session.
>
> NOTE: If you are using zsh you likely instead should put the sourcing line into ~/.zshrc
>
> Doing so ensures rvm is loaded as a function (versus as a binary), ensuring commands such as rvm use work as expected.

An additional point:

> Ensure that rvm is the last thing sourced in all of your shell profiles - e.g. it is sourced in the user specific profile after any environment variables, especially PATH are set. Otherwise, the values you set be trampled when you switch rubies.