# Ruby Installation on Mac OSX fails - please help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am extremely frustrated with ruby on Mac OS X. I have tried RVM and regular installations of ruby, and nothing seems to get it to work well. With RVM, rails throws errors at me, and with a regular installation of ruby 1.9.2-p180, somehow my computer reverts back to ruby 1.8.7 over time. Can someone please help? A detailed instruction on how to just reset my ruby installation from a clean slate would be very helpful.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: If you really really really follow the instructions of RVM really really closely, not much can go wrong. After installing RVM and installing the ruby you want, the active rvm ruby should have preference over the one installed on your system by default.

Starting over would be by removing ~/.rvm and following http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ really really closely..

really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using macports for all my needs:

1. go to www.macports.org
2. download installation dmg
3. install it
4. open a new Terminal windows (or *source ~/.profile* )
5. *port selfupdate*
6. *port search ruby*
7. pick what one want (ruby for 1.8.7, or ruby19 for 1.9.2)
8. *sudo port install ruby*
9. *port search rb-*
10. pick what want and install

everything will install into /opt - so does not interfere with your standard system binaries.

Note, than everything will compile - and take a long time.

Comment: Hi all, I just installed RVM with the instructions and rails as well. I've created a rails app and it worked for a while, but now when i try to run rails s i get this error =>  "/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:18
" can anyone please help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`rvm --default use 1.9.2`

This has been covered multiple times here. A simple search will find many questions.

See:
[Installing RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243088/installing-rvm-ruby-version-manager)

and

[i installed ruby 1.9.2 with RVM, but when i type "ruby -v" is telling me the ruby v i have is 1.8.7 (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937909/i-installed-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-but-when-i-type-ruby-v-is-telling-me-the-ruby)

Comment: sounds great. how do I make sure that rails 3 uses the rvm version of ruby?